# animate commands do not display any graphic in beamer

Tags: beamer, animate

I'm trying to display animations with `\animategraphics` or `\animateinline`, in compilation there aren't errors (I've tried the minimal working example MWE). However, in the pdf file, the images are not displayed. I have already installed the new version of `animate` package. Any idea of what to do?

Comment: what are you using for viewing the pdf?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that I had instaled Ghostscript 9.10, and the animate package need Ghostscript > 9.15.